# What is SR.SerialPortDesc? Where can I find source code of SR class that has SerialPortDesc public member?

Tags: c#, .net

I see SerialPort class source code and this class is decorated with [MonitoringDescription(SR.SerialPortDesc)] attribute. What is SR here? Where can I see its definition? I had downloaded .NET Framework 4.5.2. sources and tried to find SR definition there. I found some definitions of SR class there but no one of them includes public property or field that has "SerialPortDesc" name. Where can I find source code of SR class that has SerialPortDesc public member?

Answer (score 0):

SR in this case is most certainly a localized string resources helper class. I've seen it in use years ago but can't recall any details except that it'll give back the correct string based on the current UI locale. It exposes one property for each used string.

Comment: So, SR class instance is actually to show comments for users in their native language?

Comment: Write me please, where I can see the source code of just this SR class?

Answer (score 0):

Best I've been able to find is a text file https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System/System.txt which has all the error strings in en-US, it is obviously used to create the SR class, and has the string